# Can I transfer different text colours to a single cell using data from another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script

I have a multi-step problem I am trying to solve with either Google Sheets or Excel.

First, I have a sheet which lists all the names and the assigned classes and I need to find occurrences of the Class name and put each of the names into a single cell next to the Class name.

Then, on another sheet I have each of the names linked to one of four colours. I then need to pull the matching colour from this sheet and apply it to each instance of the name in the cell.

Eg.

Worksheet 1

```
Column A     Column B    Column C    Column D

This kid     Class A     Class C     Class B

That kid     Class C     Class D     Class H

Your kid     Class B     Class A     Class E

Other kid    Class E     Class F     Class A
```

Worksheet 2

```
This kid (in green text)

That kid (in blue text)

Your kid (in orange text)

Other kid (in red text)
```

Worksheet 3

```
Column A    Column B

Class A     This kid; That kid; Other kid

Class B     Other kid; Your kid; That kid; This kid
```

Final product

```
Column A    Column B

Class A     This kid (green text); That kid (blue text); Other kid (red text)

Class B     Other kid (red text); Your kid (orange text); That kid (blue text); This kid (green text)
```

I have been struggling with this for a couple of years and would appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 0):

This is to change colour of a part of string in a cell:

```
c.Characters(Start:=iFrom, Length:=iLen).Font.Color = vbRed
```

where c is range of a single cell. You can use it like this:

```
Sub ChangeColor(c As Range, sWhat As String, iColor As Long)

    If c.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' error

    Dim iFrom As Long, iLen As Long

    iFrom = InStr(1, c.Value, sWhat)
    If iFrom > 0 Then
        c.Characters(Start:=iFrom, Length:=Len(sWhat)).Font.Color = iColor
    End If

End Sub
```

You can check if a cell contains a specific colour this way:

```
Function IsColored(c As Range, iColor As Long) As Boolean
    IsColored = False ' default
    If c.Count > 1 Then Exit Function   ' error
    
    Dim i As Long, iLen As Long
    iLen = Len(Trim(c.Value))
    
    For i = 1 To iLen
        If c.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color = iColor Then
            IsColored = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Please note that this operates on cell values, not on strings.